# How to CSS radiobutton in IE8 ( using selectivizr)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, selectivizr

Try to use selectivizr. But I don't understant how it works..

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleie.css" />
    </noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

This how I connect it:

```
.button input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

style.css
in styleie.css same code.

Testing on IE 11 in f12 mode ( IE8 capability)

Comment: Your question.? You forgot to ask.

Comment: IE says in console that access denied

Comment: If the selectivizr is being loaded and there is no errors in the console.  It should just work for older I.E browsers. That's all to it.

Comment: On server no error, but I can't do to make selection in IE8